# How can i split text data to a list?

Tags: python, split

*I've got a text file like this*:

```
1;2;3;4
5;6;7;8
```

*And I'd like to transform it to:*

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

Using Python, how can i achieve this?*

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Have you done a tentative? Please post your code here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
data = [[int(i) for i in line.split(';')] for line in open(filename)]
```

Alternative using the csv module:

```
import csv
data = [[int(i) for i in ln] for ln in csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=';')]
```

If lists of strings are acceptable:

```
data = [line.split(';') for line in open(filename)]
```

Or the csv equivalent:

```
data = list(csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=';'))
```

Comment: by the way , i ve got a huge data and i tried to apply csv module to it and i got "MemoryError" , how  can i handle it?

Answer (score 3):

As a multi-line string:

```
>>> s = """1;2;3;4
5;6;7;8"""

>>> [[int(x) for x in a.split(';')] for a in s.splitlines()]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

As your data seems to be some sort of CSV like data, why not use python's [csv parsing module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)? This handles encoding and supports delimiters all for free.

If you just want some code, use a list comprehension and split using the `split` method of `str`:

```
result = [line.split(';') for line in text.split("\n")]
```

Answer (score 2):

`'1;2;3;4'.split(';')` will produce the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` from the string `'1;2;3;4'`, so you just need to do that for each line in your file:

```
def split_lists(filepath, sep=';'):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        line_lists = []
        for line in f:
            line_lists.append(line.split(sep))
        return line_lists
```

Or more compactly with a comprehension

```
def split_lists(filepath, sep=';'):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        return [line.split(sep) for line in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the interesting question, can be resolved by 2 map and one for loop

```
s='1;2;3;4\n5;6;7;8'
map(lambda seq: [int(i) for i in seq], map(lambda x:x.split(';'), s.split('\n')))
```